# Laravel pagination with relations and additional checks

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, pagination, laravel-collection

I'm trying to make pagination with my Conversation model, which has many Message models. (`$this->hasMany('App\Message');`)

So each conversation can have multiple messages (conversation is something like thread). Messages have two possible directions outgoing and incoming.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all conversations that have at least three messages. And where the last message has outgoing direction.

```
 $con = Conversation::with(['messages', 'messages.sms_status'])->paginate(15);
```

This is how I get my conversation so far, just basic pagination.
I use pagination because I can have a lot of conversations around a few millions. That is why I need to pull out only conversations that have at least three messages and where the last message has outgoing direction.

I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: How do you define the direction? Is it in the `sms_status` field?

Comment: No, sms_status is relation of messages. Message has direction field @Mozammil

Comment: I added my answer. Let me know if it works out for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I would probably define a `lastMessage()` relationship as follows:

```
public function lastMessage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Message::class)->latest(); 
}
```

.. and then I should be able to constrain my query as follows:

```
$con = Conversation::with('messages.sms_status')
    ->whereHas('lastMessage', function($query) {
        $query->where('direction', 'outgoing');
    })
    ->has('messages', '>=', 3)
    ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereHas()` and constraining the `with()`, since you can pass a 3rd parameter to `whereHas()` that indicates a count. Like:

```
$con = Conversation::with(['messages' => function($query){
    return $query->orderBy('outgoing', 'desc')
}, 'messages.sms_status'])
->whereHas('messages', null, '>=', 3)->paginate(15);
```

This will return all conversations with at least 3 messages, ordered by whatever you call your outgoing field.

Comment: OP wants last message to be outgoing :)

Comment: Okey, this whereHas solved my problem, it has only one error.
whereHas('messages', null,'>=', 3) . Because second parameter is callback and third one is operator. But what still does not work is this orderBy. I need to get conversation only if last message has direction outgoing can ? I't would be something like if ($lastMessage->direction == 'outgoing') return $record @NMahurin

Comment: That would use the callback in the `whereHas()` to get. It's hard to write that out without knowing what fields are on the messages table though.